# Let $x$ be a real number. Prove that if $x^2\lt x$, then $x\lt1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x$ be a real number. Prove that if $x^2\lt x$, then $x\lt1$

I do not know how to proceed. I assume its proof is by contrapositive?

Answer (score 5):

$$x^2\lt x$$
$$x^2-x\lt 0$$
$$x(x-1)\lt 0$$
Thus, either $x\lt 0$ and $x\gt 1$

or

$x\gt0$ and $x\lt1$.

Clearly, the former is not possible.

Hence,
$$0\lt x\lt1$$

Answer (score 3):

Proof by contrapositive is the easiest: let $x \ge 1$, then $x^2 = x \cdot x >= x$. Q.E.D.

Comment: You don't exclude the possibility of $x$ being negative.

Comment: I'm *assuming* $x$ is positive to begin with. That's the whole idea of proving the contrapositive.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have misread the question - based on the top answer I thought you are supposed to prove $0<x<1$. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

$x^2\lt x$ implies $x>0$ since $x^2\ge0$ for all $x$.

Therefore we can cancel $x$ in $x^2\lt x$ and get $x < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 < x$

$\frac{x^2}{x} < 1$

$x < 1$

Comment: You need $x>0$ for the second step.

Comment: @lhf but how? If I answer it like $x^2 - x<0$ then I know. But in this case don't know.

Comment: @lhf as $x>x^2\geq 0\implies x>0$

Answer (score 1):

exactly. if $x\geq 1$ (1), as $x>0$ and $x=x$ (2), (1)$\dot{}$(2) gives you $x^2\geq x$